# T-SQL: I'm trying to get the latest row of a column but also the sum of another column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

I have the following table, it displays the `SalesQty` and the `StockQty` grouped by `Article`, `Supplier`, `Branch` and `Month`.

```
╔════════╦════════╦══════════╦═════════╦══════════╦══════════╗
║ Month  ║ Branch ║ Supplier ║ Article ║ SalesQty ║ StockQty ║
╠════════╬════════╬══════════╬═════════╬══════════╬══════════╣
║ 201811 ║    333 ║        2 ║    3122 ║        4 ║ 11       ║
║ 201811 ║    345 ║        1 ║    1234 ║        2 ║ 10       ║
║ 201811 ║    345 ║        1 ║    4321 ║        3 ║ 11       ║
║ 201812 ║    333 ║        2 ║    3122 ║        2 ║ 4        ║
║ 201812 ║    345 ║        1 ║    1234 ║        3 ║ 12       ║
║ 201812 ║    345 ║        1 ║    4321 ║        4 ║ 5        ║
║ 201901 ║    333 ║        2 ║    3122 ║        1 ║ 8        ║
║ 201901 ║    345 ║        1 ║    1234 ║        6 ║ 9        ║
║ 201901 ║    345 ║        1 ║    4321 ║        2 ║ 8        ║
║ 201902 ║    333 ║        2 ║    3122 ║        7 ║ NULL     ║
║ 201902 ║    345 ║        1 ║    1234 ║        4 ║ 13       ║
║ 201902 ║    345 ║        1 ║    4321 ║        1 ║ 10       ║
╚════════╩════════╩══════════╩═════════╩══════════╩══════════╝
```

Now I want to sum the `SalesQty` and get the **latest** `StockQty` and group them by `Article, Supplier, Branch`.

The final result should look like this:

```
╔════════╦══════════╦═════════╦═════════════╦════════════════╗
║ Branch ║ Supplier ║ Article ║ SumSalesQty ║ LatestStockQty ║
╠════════╬══════════╬═════════╬═════════════╬════════════════╣
║    333 ║        2 ║    3122 ║          14 ║           NULL ║
║    345 ║        1 ║    1234 ║          15 ║             13 ║
║    345 ║        1 ║    4321 ║          10 ║             10 ║
╚════════╩══════════╩═════════╩═════════════╩════════════════╝
```

I already tried this but it gives me an error, and i have no idea what i have to do in this case.

I've made this example so you can try it by yourself. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=a264611fd76f8c453e0edbc2c4f348ed)

```
SELECT      
    Branch, 
    Supplier,
    Article,
    SumSalesQty = SUM(SalesQty),
    -- my attempt
    LatestStockQty = (SELECT StockQty FROM TestTable i 
                      WHERE MAX(Month) = Month
                        AND TT.Branch = i. Branch
                        AND TT.Supplier = i.Branch
                        AND TT.Article = i.Branch)
FROM        
    TestTable TT
GROUP BY    
    Branch, Supplier, Article
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

We can try using `ROW_NUMBER` here, to isolate the latest record for each group:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Branch, Supplier, Article
                                   ORDER BY Month DESC) rn,
        SUM(SalesQty) OVER (PARTITION BY Branch, Supplier, Article) SumSalesQty
    FROM TestTable t
)

SELECT
    Month,
    Branch,
    Supplier,
    Article,
    SumSalesQty,
    StockQty
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Inside the CTE we compute, for each `Branch`/`Supplier`/`Article` group a row number value, starting with 1 for the most recent month.  We also compute the sum of the sales quantity over the same partition.  Then, we only need to select all rows from that CTE where the row number is equal to 1.

[image]

### Demo

Answer (score 3):

A similar approach but without the CTE

```
    SELECT top 1 with ties  
              Branch 
            , Supplier
            , Article
            , SUM(SalesQty) OVER (PARTITION BY Branch, Supplier, Article) SumSalesQty
            , tt.StockQty  as LatestStockQty
FROM        TestTable TT
order by    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Branch, Supplier, Article ORDER BY Month DESC)
```

Comment: Most people forgot that analytic functions can also be used in an `ORDER BY` clause +1.