# Results for a particular order and also the sum of multiple orders, for each customer

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to return a single row for each customer that purchased a particular product, with the most recent order of that product and the amount of that order, and also the sum of the amounts of all orders with that product for that customer (in a particular date range).

Here's my base FROM clause:

```
FROM Customers c
  JOIN Orders o
    ON c.ID = o.CustomerID
  JOIN OrderDetails od
    ON o.ID = od.OrderID
    AND od.ProductID = 111
```

Simplified data set:

```
c.ID | c.Name
-------------
1    | Bob
2    | Jane
3    | Bill
4    | Mary

o.ID | o.CustomerID | o.Date
--------------------------------
10   | 1            | 6/10/2021
11   | 3            | 8/1/2021
12   | 2            | 8/4/2021
13   | 4            | 10/20/2022
14   | 1            | 11/18/2022
15   | 4            | 2/1/2023
16   | 4            | 4/12/2023

od.ID | od.OrderID | od.ProductID | od.Amount
---------------------------------------------
100   | 10         | 111          | 100
101   | 11         | 111          | 50
102   | 12         | 111          | 25
103   | 13         | 111          | 10
104   | 14         | 111          | 300
105   | 15         | 111          | 120
106   | 16         | 111          | 60
```

Expected results:

```
c.ID | c.Name | LatestOrder | LatestOrderAmount | TotalAllAmounts
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1    | Bob    | 11/18/2022  | 300               | 400
2    | Jane   | 8/4/2021    | 25                | 25
3    | Bill   | 8/1/2021    | 50                | 50
4    | Mary   | 4/12/2023   | 60                | 190
```

Nothing I've tried with standard aggregates and grouping works because when you get the sum, you have to group by all the other stuff, including the amount from the order with max date, so it returns one row per order (specifically one row per $X amount) and then only sums that order because it's counted as a separate grouping. You can do a max date and a sum of amounts, but putting the single $amount that's in the max-date order throws it all off.

I think the answer from [T-SQL: I'm trying to get the latest row of a column but also the sum of another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54923664/t-sql-im-trying-to-get-the-latest-row-of-a-column-but-also-the-sum-of-another) is on the right track, but I can't figure out how to put it all together with multiple tables.

Answer (score 2):

One possible option is with a combination of `Apply` and a *window function* for the last amount:

```
select c.Id, c.Name, Max(o.Date)LatestOrder, 
  Max(o.LastOrderAmount)LastOrderAmount, 
  sum(o.Amount)TotalAllAmounts
from Customers c
cross apply (
  select o.date, od.Amount, 
    Last_Value(od.Amount) over(
      partition by o.customerId 
        order by o.Date 
        rows between current row and unbounded following
      ) LastOrderAmount
  from Orders o 
  join OrderDetails od on o.ID = od.OrderID
  and o.CustomerID = c.Id
)o
group by c.Id, c.Name
order by c.Id;
```

See a [demo Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/l0Kq5jjQ)

Comment: `FIRST_VALUE(od.Amount) OVER (partition by o.customerId order by o.Date DESC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)` feels more idiomatic, although would imagine performance will depend on which way the index is sorted

Comment: I suppose either could be used with the appropriate window and sort, it just feels more natural to me to use the last_value where it *is* the last value that's logically required, provided it doesn't incur an additional sort that could be avoided with the opposite method!

Answer (score 0):

Turning your example data into DDL/DML:

```
DECLARE @Customers TABLE (ID INT, Name VARCHAR(20));
INSERT INTO @Customers (ID, Name) VALUES (1, 'Bob'), (2, 'Jane'), (3, 'Bill'), (4, 'Mary');

DECLARE @Orders TABLE (ID INT, CustomerID INT, Date DATE);
INSERT INTO @Orders (ID, CustomerID, Date) VALUES
(10, 1, '6/10/2021'), (11, 3, '8/1/2021'), (12, 2, '8/4/2021'), (13, 4, '10/20/2022'), 
(14, 1, '11/18/2022'), (15, 4, '2/1/2023'), (16, 4, '4/12/2023');

DECLARE @OrderProducts TABLE (ID INT, OrderID INT, ProductID INT, Amount DECIMAL(10,3));
INSERT INTO @OrderProducts (ID, OrderID, ProductID, Amount) VALUES
(100, 10, 111, 100), (101, 11, 111, 50 ), (102, 12, 111, 25 ), (103, 13, 111, 10 ), 
(104, 14, 111, 300), (105, 15, 111, 120), (106, 16, 111, 60 );
```

This is fairly straightforward when you can think in windowed functions. All we really need here is a total aggregate, and a way to identify the most recent row in that total aggregate:

```
SELECT a.CustomerID, c.Name, a.mxDate AS LatestOrderDate, SUM(CASE WHEN a.Date = a.mxDate THEN Amount END) AS LatestOrderAmount, SUM(a.Amount) AS TotalAllAmounts
  FROM (
SELECT op.OrderID, op.Amount, o.CustomerID, o.Date, MAX(o.Date) OVER (PARTITION BY o.CustomerID ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS mxDate
  FROM @OrderProducts op
    INNER JOIN @Orders o
      ON op.OrderID = o.ID
 WHERE op.ProductID = 111
   AND o.Date BETWEEN '2021-06-10' AND '2023-08-16'
       ) a
  INNER JOIN @Customers c
    ON a.CustomerID = c.ID
 GROUP BY a.CustomerID, c.Name, a.mxDate;
```

| CustomerID | Name | LatestOrderDate | LatestOrderAmount | TotalAllAmounts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Bob | 2022-11-18 | 300.000 | 400.000 |
| 2 | Jane | 2021-08-04 | 25.000 | 25.000 |
| 3 | Bill | 2021-08-01 | 50.000 | 50.000 |
| 4 | Mary | 2023-04-12 | 60.000 | 190.000 |

Comment: That didn't quite work when I used your code (returned zero results), but that could just be the front-end software I have to use. It accepts straight SQL in the 'advanced' section, but it's finicky. I thank you profusely, however, for dropping the last missing piece into place for me: using SUM with the LatestOrderAmount CASE. Then it's also an aggregate function so it doesn't have to be in the GROUP BY clause, thereby solving my issue. Duh! Thank you, thank you.